# how to use requests raise error in python

Tags: python, exception, python-requests, python-3.6

Iam using python to fetch content from some urls. So I have a list of urls, and all are fine except one of them where I get a 404. I wanted to fetch this like:

```
for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)

    try:
        r.raise_for_status()
    except RuntimeError:
        print('error: could not get content from url because of {}'.format(r.status_code))
```

But now, the exception raised by raise_for_status() is not fetched but just printed out? How can I print my own error code if its raised?

Comment: I don't get the question. What do you mean by "fetched"? And currently you're printing your own error _message_, so how's that different from what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your `try catch block`

```
try:
     r = requests.get(url)
     r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as error:
     print error
```

Comment: Replace the `print error` with the user exception like `raise Exception("error: could not get content from url because of...")` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own exception `class` and just raise that,

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass
...
...
for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    try:
        r.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as error:
        raise MyException('error: could not get content from url because of {}'.format(r.status_code))
```